# jQuery each loop works for first time only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 `divs`, each div has another div (for labels), and then the values.

I want those labels to also be added to the left of the items.

https://jsfiddle.net/eavbLgnq/

Current HTML output:

```
ID
Name
4343
Alpha
657
Team
Age
Job
23
Teacher
44
Coder
```

Desired results:

```
ID
Name
ID 4343
Name Alpha
ID 657
Name Team
Age
Job
Age 23
Job Teacher
Age 44
Job Coder
```

What I'm getting:

```
ID
Name
ID 4343
Name Alpha
ID 657
Name Team
Age
Job
ID 23
Name Teacher
ID 44
Name Coder
```

Jquery code:

```
  let pu_cells = []
  let table_ = $('.pu')

  table_.each(function(){
    let this_pu = $(this)
      this_pu.find(".pu-row_0 .pu-pk-cell").each(function(){
        pu_cells.push($(this).text())
      })

      this_pu.find('.pu-row:not(.pu-row_0)').each(function(i){
        $(this).find('.pu-pk-cell').each(function(j){
          $(this).html('<span class="pu-cell-label"> '+pu_cells[j]+'</span> ' + $(this).text())
        })
      })
})
```

Comment: _"Current HTML output"_ - That's not HTML. Please add a [mcve] with actual markup for in- and expected output _in the question itself_

Comment: I added a link https://jsfiddle.net/eavbLgnq/

Comment: I added HTML before but the question didn't submit due to error (you have much code, add some content)

Comment: Then it's not a [**minimal** reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If you want to help, just go to the link and everything you need is there.. thanks!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/) -> You're supposed to add all relevant information (also known as [mcve]) **in the question itself**. Not everyone might be able to access your external stuff, or it is temporarily offline or vanished forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never reset the value of `pu_cells` and for second `div` it has first cell value too (`ID,Name` I mean).

So just put `let pu_cells = []` in each loop.

```js
        let table_ = $('.pu')

        table_.each(function () {
            let pu_cells = []
            let this_pu = $(this)
            this_pu.find(".pu-row_0 .pu-pk-cell").each(function () {
                pu_cells.push($(this).text())
            })

            this_pu.find('.pu-row:not(.pu-row_0)').each(function (i) {
                $(this).find('.pu-pk-cell').each(function (j) {
                    $(this).html('<span class="pu-cell-label"> ' + pu_cells[j] + '</span> ' + $(this).text())
                })
            })
        })
```

```css
 .pu-cell-label {
            color: red;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="pu pu_0">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="pu-row pu-row_0">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">ID</div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">Name</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pu-row pu-row_1">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">4343</div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">Alpha</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pu-row pu-row_2">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">657</div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">Team</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pu pu_1">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="pu-row pu-row_0">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">Age</div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">Job</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pu-row pu-row_1">
                    <div>
                        <div class="pu-da-row">
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">23</div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">Teacher</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pu-row pu-row_2">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">44</div>
                            <div class="pu-pk-cell">Coder</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```